# Reading isLoggedIn from a file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render a regular login/signup for if the user is not logged in and a dashboard if the user is logged in. I'm currently doing it using a static react hook

```
const App = () => {
    const [isLoggedIn, SetIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    if(isLoggedIn === false){
        return <Content/>
    }
    return <Dashboard/>

};
export default App;
```

My questions are:

1. How do I write a file/sqlite (what's the best practise) to store the value of isLoggedIn at the time of sign in?
2. How do I read this value when the app starts and serve the right component?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `localStorage`:

```
const App = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');    

    if(isLoggedIn === false){
        return <Content/>
    }
    return <Dashboard/>

};
export default App;
```

And then when you update the logged in state you do like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', YOUR_VALUE)
```

The only way this could be deleted is if the user clears the browser history/cache, but you should be OK.